# Where does the dinging sound come from?

Tags: seat-belt

When you drive without a seatbelt, the dinging sound comes on. Where does it come from? Under the dash? behind a panel?

2013 Toyota Highlander
2003 Toyota Matrix

I know how to stop the sound. This was just a thought that popped up in my head.

Comment: which car do you have?

Comment: Depending on the car, it can come from it's own speaker or through the audio system. In your case ... who knows.

Comment: May I ask why you wouldn't want to put a seatbelt on?

Comment: @Dan Nah, I put the belt on every time. I just had this question out of curiousity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be coming from your speaker system. Your seat has a pressure switch that tells the system whether someone is sitting on it. If so, and you're not wearing a seatbelt, it will go off. The solution is to disconnect the plug to the switch. The danger is that you may inadvertently disconnect the airbag switch and cause weird lights and/or alarms to go off.

Comment: Not only weird lights/stored codes but you would also disable the airbag system in the car by unhooking the ODS and this is only possible on the passenger side. I'm not aware of  any type of weighing devices for driver seats. More likely its just a switch in the belt buckle detecting if its hooked or not on driver side.

Answer (score 2):

As Anarach says, this will entirely depend on the car in question. It can be easily stopped in any car by simply wearing the seatbelt...

Comment: The make / model / year have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure on most Toyota's the seat belt and door chimes come from a built in speaker inside the combo meter(instrument cluster). Quite a few other makes/models do this as well. If I remember correctly on the toyota's the bcm collects most of the different input signals for chimes (doors ajar, seat belts, etc..) then relays it to the combo meter which activates the built in buzzer.